# Two different SelectItems return single selected value

Tags: jsf

I have a country class:

```
public class Country{
     private Long id;
     private String name;
}
```

and a person class that has two Country fields

```
public class Person{
    private Country nationality;
    private Country nationality2;
}
```

Now in JSF I use `<f:selectItems>` to return list of countries to select nationalities as following:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{mybean.person.nationality.id}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.countryList}" var="var" itemValue="#{var.id}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{mybean.person.nationality2.id}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.countryList}" var="var" itemValue="#{var.id}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{mybean.save}" update="sometable @form"/>
</h:form>
```

Now the weird problem is that when I submit the form the value assigned to the second field (nationality2) is assigned to both nationality and nationality2 regardless of what has been selected for the first field. For example if the `selected value for nationality is 1` and the `selected value for nationality2 is 2`, when I submit the form `both fields have the value 2`. Why is this occuring?

PS: JSF implementation is Mojarra 2.1.3

Comment: A suppose that `countryList` is list of `Cantry` objects. So where did `code` property came from? I see just `name` and `id`.

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo. Now I've fixed it!

Comment: Did you double checked `getter` and `setter` for `nationality` and `nationality2`? Maybe you have some copy paste issue.

Comment: Yes I have, I've even written some print outs in the setters to make sure what values are assigned.

Comment: OK. Is your `getCountryList()` method just returning list or you are generating list in it?

Comment: No it is just returning list retrieved from the database.

Comment: Don't tell that you are executing query in `getter`?

Comment: No I'm not, list data is preloaded in the model.

Comment: Setting the ID of an entity instead of the entity itself is at least  very strange. Use a converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused because you're setting copies of the same `Country` reference as selected value and then manipulating only the `id` property. All changes made in one reference get reflected in all other references as well.

E.g.

```
Country country = new Country();
person.setNationality1(country);
person.setNationality2(country);
country.setId(1); // Gets reflected in both nationalities!
```

You'd better set the whole `Country` entity as value instead of manipulating its properties. Create a `Converter` which converts between `Country` and `id`:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Country.class)
public class CountryConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return (value instanceof Country) ? ((Country) value).getId() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!value.matches("\\d+")) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Invalid country ID: " + value));
        }

        Long countryId = Long.valueOf(value);
        MyBean myBean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{myBean}", MyBean.class);

        for (Country country : myBean.getCountries()) {
            if (countryId.equals(country.getId())) {
                return country;
            }
        }

        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Unknown country ID: " + value));
    }

}
```

and use it as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{mybean.person.nationality1}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.countries}" var="country" itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{mybean.person.nationality2}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.countries}" var="country" itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give your Second `selectOneMenu` another name for `var`. For Example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{mybean.person.nationality2.id}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.countryList}" var="var2" itemValue="#{var2.code}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Otherwise you overwrite your changes in the (first) variable `var` by changing the second `selectOneMenu`.

**EDIT:**
If it does not solve the problem, try for tests to create a second `countryList` (countryList2) and attach it to the second `selectOneMenu`.

If the value still stays the same, the failure must be in the getters or setters.

Comment: I've tried that too, but it did no good. Could it be a JSF bug?

Comment: i really think that s JSF bug can be excluded. You can debug and try to find out where person.nationality is overwritten with person.nationality2