# Converter class throwing exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have p:selectOneMenu in my JSF page and when I run my JSF page I am getting the following exception from Converter class.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object 5634 is of type java.lang.String; 
expected type: test.entity.Employee
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I have the following in Entity class

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private String employeeNumber;
private String employeeName;

/* getters and setters */
```

EmployeeConverter class

```
@Component("employeeConverter")
@FacesConverter(forClass = Employee.class)

@Inject
EmployeeService employeeService;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {

    if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    EmployeeService employeeService= (EmployeeService ) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
            getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "employeeService");
    return employeeService.getEmployees();
}

@Override   
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {

            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof Employee) {
                Employee emp = (Employee) object;
                String val = emp.getEmployeeNumber();
                return val;
            } else {
throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + 
object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " +
Employee.class.getName());
            }
}
```

and in jsf page

```
 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{mb.employee}" converter="#{employeeConverter}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{cmb.employeeList}" var="emp"
 itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" itemValue="#{emp.employeeNumber}"/>
 <p:ajax  listener="#{mb.handleChange}"  process="@this"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Update 1**

Modified Converter method `getAsObject`

```
private List<Employee> employee;

@Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component,
            String value) {
        System.out.println("reached in converter");
        try {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                employee = getEmployeeService().getEmployees();
                for (Employee emp : employee) {
                    if (emp.getEmployeeNUmber() == value) {
                        return emp;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception from getAsObject  " + e.getMessage());            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Update 2**

```
ManagedBean

@PostConstruct
    public void loadEmployees(){

        try {           
            List<Employee> emp = getEmployeeService().getEmployees();           
            employeeList = emp; 

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("exception from loadEmployees "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know if that's the issue but you have `#{emp.emploeeNumber}` misstyped.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Sorry it was a typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: Can you specify your `getAsObject` method as well?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I have included `getAsObject` method. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious how you are injecting your service entity in the converter? is your service a JPA Dao?

Comment: @fareed I have declared it as `@Component`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `getAsObject` method you're doing nothing with your reached value. Here you're going to receive your `#{emp.employeeNumber}`, so you have to convert it into an `Employee` (probably you'll have to implement a method which loads an `Employee` by id using service locator) and return the object itself.

You're also referencing the convertor with an EL (`#{employeeConverter}`), you have to do it in a direct way. Finally, the List of elements has to be composed by `SelectItem`, in order to make [`f:selectItems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html) tag work.

Comment: Not sure how can I do this, can I use like `return KeyFactory.stringToKey( value );` as mentioned [here](http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/01/11/jsf-2-custom-converter/)

Comment: You're performing `employeeService.getEmployees();` operation. Here you have all the employees and your value is keeping the selected employee id. Just search for that id in your list and return the employee itself. That's what convertors do, they get an object from a received `String`.

Comment: I have modified Converter class `getAsObject` method, added in my original question as Update 1. I am still getting the same exception as earlier. I have put a println statement at the beginning of `getAsObject` method and that is not getting printed either. Anything wrong with my modified method? If so kindly let me know.

Comment: Converter has not to be evaluated, put `employeeConverter` instead of `#{employeeConverter}`.

Comment: It doesn't accept anything other than this format `#{employeeConverter}`

Comment: Error is `Expression Error: Named Object: employeeConverter not found.`

Comment: Your converter is not being found. Is your class implementing `Converter` interface? Follow this [convention](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/) and delete useless annotations.

Comment: I have resolved that, I have added as @FacesConverter("categoryConverter")`' But still it doesn't come to `getAsObject`, however it has come to `getAsString` method in `Converter` class, as I have put a `println` statement in `getAsString` method

Comment: `getAsObject` is called when a request is done. For example if you make an ajax event when user switches between options, or also when you're about to submit the whole form. `getAsString` is obviusly being called because the page is asking for the `select` component when loaded.

Comment: But before page gets loaded I am getting `1IllegalArgumentException` How to deal with this?

Comment: Where are you getting that? Please update your question and publish your actual code with the whole converter class.

Comment: I am getting this exception in getAsString method of Converter class as I have mentioned in my original question. At this line I am getting the exception, `throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + 
object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " +
Employee.class.getName());`. It is included in my question, method is `getAsString`. Thanks

Comment: Can you do debugging and tell me what is reaching there as `object`? Probably you're not implementing `#{cmb.employeeList}` properly. If you do not publish how you create that list I can do nothing..

Comment: I have included how I am getting employeeList in ManagedBean as Update 2 in my question.

Comment: Object it is reaching is `5432` which is  `employeeNumber`.

Comment: You can't bind that to a `List` of `Employee` directly. You need List<SelectItem> if you are going to use `f:selectItems`. [Take a look](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/jsf/select_one_menu_converter.html)

Comment: Yes that helped to resolve that. Thanks a lot. Still `getAsObject` is not being invoked though.

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer. To make `getAsObject` work, look at my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Don't assign the string to the item value, you need to assign the converted object (Employee) itself.

change to `itemValue="#{emp}"`

See BalusC answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952103/two-different-selectitems-return-single-selected-value/14978360#14978360).

Comment: It is not necessary to do that at all. You can pass the whole object reference as you say or the id as OP is trying to do, but the must is that you've to somehow recover the object into the converter. Look at this http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/01/11/jsf-2-custom-converter/

Comment: What I meant is that he needs to recover the object itself and assign it as the object. You are right, he can pass the id of the object, but the point is if he is passing a string why would he need a converter for that?

Comment: I really prefer to pass the whole object reference as value, however the real problem here is his `getAsObject` method.

Comment: I agree, when I answered this question, the getAsObject method was not in the question. Now I see it.

Comment: @fareed If I change to `itemValue="#{emp}"`, then there is no `IllegalArgumentException`, however when I select a value from menu, I am getting `NP`E in `handleChange` method of `ManagedBean`