# commandButton actionListener invoking selectOneMenu listener

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 and with Primefaces 3.4.2

I have a popup dialog where I have few `inputText`, `selectOneMenu`, `autoComplete` and `<p:commandButton`

I have the following in selectOneMenu `<p:ajax update="dept" listener="#{empMB.loadDepartments}" />`

When I click commandButton, listener and Converter class of selectOneMenu is getting invoked.
Method I have for commandButton is not getting invoked. What could be the reason for this?

JSF Code

```
    <p:dialog header="My Panel" style="font-weight:bold"
                    widgetVar="NewDialog" resizable="false" id="NewDlg"
                    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" appendToBody="true"
                    modal="true" position="center top" width="850" height="450">
                    <h:form id="createform">                    
                    <p:panelGrid   columns="6">         

                        <h:outputLabel value="Employee # " for="emp" />
                        <p:autoComplete value="#{mymb.selectedEmployee}"
                            id="emp" minQueryLength="3" 
                            completeMethod="#{mymb.complete}" 
                            var="p" itemLabel="#{p.employeeName}" itemValue="#{p.employeeNumber}"                
                            forceSelection="true" >                           
                             <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{mymb.handleSelect}" 
                             update ="empnumber phone  /> 
                               <p:column>#{p.employeeName} - #{p.employeeNumber}</p:column>
                        </p:autoComplete>                         

                        <h:outputLabel  value="Department"  />
                        <p:inputText id="empnumber" value="#{mymb.employeeDetail.department}" >
                        </p:inputText>                        
                        <h:outputLabel value="Contact #" for="phone" />
                        <p:inputText id="phone" value="#{mymb.employeeDetail.phone}">
                        </p:inputText>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Employee Number" for="employeenumber" />
                        <p:inputText id="employeenumber" value="#{mymb.employeeDetail.employeeNumber}">
                        </p:inputText>                        
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:separator />
                    <p:panelGrid columns="6">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Employees" for="employees" />
    <h:selectOneMenu id="employees" value="#{empMB.employees}" converter="#{employeesConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{empMB.employeesItems}" var="cat"
    itemLabel="#{cat.employeesName}" itemValue="#{cat.employeesCode}"/>
    <p:ajax update="dept" listener="#{empMB.loadDepartments}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputLabel value="Dept employees" for="dept" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="dept" value="#{empMB.department}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{empMB.departmentList}" var="dep" 
    itemLabel="#{dep.departmentName}"
    itemValue="#{dep.departmentCode}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" 
                actionListener="#{empMB.saveRequest}" />

                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:separator />
                    </h:form>
                   </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Do you get some error? How is your backing bean `save` method? It's normal for the converter to be called as I told you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14996818/1199132).

Comment: @XtremeBiker No I do not get any error, not in Firebug as well. My method in bean `public void saveRequest(ActionEvent event){
  
  System.out.println("In save "+employee.getEmployee());
//  persistemployeeService.create(employee);  
 }`

Comment: How do you want to get it called if you are invoking another method?

Comment: @XtremeBiker sorry typo

Comment: What is a type of `empMB.employees`?

Comment: Remove `ActionEvent event` param from your methods signature. It's not necessary at all.

Comment: @partlov employees is of `private Employees employees = new Employees();`

Comment: @partlov I have added 'process="@this"` in commandButton and that solved the issue

Comment: @XtremeBiker I have added 'process="@this"` in commandButton and that solved the issue

Comment: If that solves your issues than validation failed somewhere else.

Comment: @partlov Could you kind enough to be more specific?

Comment: Well JSF probably failed to set some field when you processed whole form, for example `department` or some other. Maybe type was wrong, or converter failed. Add `p:message` in form and update it without `process="@this"` and you will probably see something.

Comment: @partlov You are spot on, there is an error in second selectOneMenu with `Conversion Error`. Thanks for pointing it out. If you could provide as an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well JSF probably failed to set some field when you processed whole form, for example department or some other. Maybe type was wrong, or converter failed. Add `p:message` in form and update it without `process="@this"` and you will probably see something.